# Difference between two ways of declaring an object on the stack

Tags: c++, class, object, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

What's the difference between the following two declarations, assuming I have not specified a copy constructor and `operator=` in class `Beatle`?

`Beatle john(paul);`

and

`Beatle john = paul;`

Edit:

In objects assignment, the operator `=` implicitly calls the copy constructor unless told otherwise?

Comment: Why did you choose `john` and `paul` as variable name and `Dog` as type?

Comment: @Nawaz what's wrong with dogs called john and paul?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Wrong or right, till now I didn't say anything of that sort. I'm just curious *why* he chose that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're different grammatical constructions. The first one is *direct initialization*, the second is *copy initialization*. They behave virtually identically, only that the second requires a non-`explicit` constructor.*

Neither has anything to do with the assignment operator, as both lines are *initializations*.

To wit: `const int i = 4;` is fine, but `const int i; i = 4;` is not.

*) More accurately: The second version does not work if the relevant constructor is declared `explicit`. More generally, thus, direct-initialization affords you one "free" conversion:

```
struct Foo { Foo(std::string) {} };

Foo x("abc");  // OK: char(&)[4] -> const char * -> std::string -> Foo
Foo y = "abd"; // Error: no one-step implicit conversion of UDTs
```

---

To address your edit: To understand the assignment operator, just break it up into parts. Suppose `Foo` has the obvious `operator=(const Foo & rhs)`. We can say `x = y;`, which just calls the operator directly with `rhs` being `y`. Now consider this:

```
x = "abc";              // error, no one-step implicit conversion
x = std::string("abc"); // fine, uses Foo(std::string), then copy
x = Foo("abc");         // fine, implicit char(&)[4] -> const char* -> std::string, then as above
```

Comment: could you provide a reference? (i'm just curious...)

Comment: @xmoex: It's all in section 8.5.

Answer (score 2):

First is Direct Initialization & second is Copy Initialization.

**Direct initialization** means the object is initialized using a single (possibly conversion) constructor, and is equivalent to the form `T t(u);`:

```
U u;
T t1(u); // calls T::T( U& ) or similar
```

**Copy initialization** means the object is initialized using the copy constructor, after first calling a user-defined conversion if necessary, and is equivalent to the form `T t = u;`:

```
T t2 = t1;  // same type: calls T::T( T& ) or similar
T t3 = u;   // different type: calls T::T( T(u) )
            //  or T::T( u.operator T() ) or similar
```

Copy Initialization does not work if the constructor is declared `explicit`.

References:
**[This](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/036.htm)** entry in Herb Sutter's GOTW should be a good read.

---

To answer your edited Question:
`=` has a different meaning in depending on how it is used.

If `=` is used in an expression in which the object is being *created and initialized* at the same time, then `=` is not treated as Assignment Operator but as Copy Initialization.

If `=` is being used to assign one object to another, *after* the object has been created then it results in call to Assignment Operator.

Comment: So it means that `Beatle john(paul);` and `Beatle john = paul:` are equivalent?

Comment: @LeifEricson: huh? The answer explains, how they are **not** equivalent, Which part of the answer is not clear to you or confuses you?

Comment: `T t2 = t1;  // same type: calls T::T( T& ) or similar` which means that this line calls to a copy constructor, which means in this case that they are equivalent.